# Will_paginate in Dynamic pages as "search"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm having trouble with `will_paginate`. It works perfectly with static pages but not in dynamic pages. In my controller I have:

```
def search 
  @prods = Prods.find_all_by_producer(params[:producer])
  @items = @prods.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= will_paginate @items %>
```

The first 10 items (the first page) are well displayed but when I try to navigate to next pages, I have:

```
undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass
Parameters : {"page"=>"2","locale"=>nil}
```

I understand the issue, there is no `params[:producer]` when it calls the second page so `@prods` returns `nil`. But how to do that, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the @prods as param like this:

{:producer=>@producer} %>

Source: http://www.cowboycoded.com/2009/09/08/appending-parameters-on-a-will_paginate-link/